# How to add .class files in to Eclipse project bin folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

To create a jar file I copied some .class files to bin folder of Eclipse project after cleaning the project, but when I'm creating the jar file I can't select those additionally added class files. Why is that ? How can I create a jar file with new class files?

Comment: What's the reason for doing this? Can't you just add the library with all the class files?

Comment: Can I create a jar file which contains referenced libraries also?? Is it possible in Eclipse?

Comment: @Grant: Yes, you can include libraries in your Java project classpath in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `.class` files you would like to consume in your project you can either turn them into a jar and use that, or create a separate folder in your java project containing the .class files in their package hierarchy.  Then right-click and use `Build Path>Configure build path...>Libraries` to *Add Class Folder...*.  Whenever eclipse builds the project, it can use the .class files (and they won't be wiped out by a clean).

Answer (score 1):

If you add .class files manually to bin folder, then you need to refresh the Eclipse project in order for it include the manually added file in the exported jar file.

However, it is important to note that Eclipse may delete the manually added files when you recompile or clean up and rebuild the project.

Please follow what others suggested, include external library in the classpath.

Comment: Yes I have already refreshed it...but how can I create new jar file including newly added class files also ?

Comment: After refreshing, you can go through the "export" wizard to export into jar file.

Comment: Yes. I tried File >> Export >> jar and then I created the jar, but that new jar file doesn't contain copied class files in to the bin folder.

Comment: After exporting do you still see manually copied files in the bin folder?.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really good tutorial on Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html
There's also an example half-way down the page.

Hope this helps.